# How do I force the URL for a certain folder to be /index.html if hitting /

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to force the URL to be index.html if someone hits a particular directory. How do I do this with .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1/index.html [L,R=301]
```